# Why i get error when try to open sqlite database in android BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android

I'm beginner in android and call alarm manager in main activity,into the alarm manager write this code:

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static Context myContext;
    @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://myHOST.ir/oflineValue.aspx");
    }
    private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                        String DATABASE_NAME = "TEMPFOOD";
                        String TABLE_NAME = "tempData";
                        SQLiteDatabase db;
                            db=SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME,myContext.MODE_PRIVATE,  null);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
        @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            }
    }
}
```

but in this line:

```
db=SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME,myContext.MODE_PRIVATE,  null);
```

i get this error:
[image]

why i get that error?

Comment: Your code is unreliable. Once `onReceive()` returns, your process may be terminated within milliseconds, and your work will not get done. Plus, the device may fall asleep before your work completes. Move your code from your `AsyncTask` into an `IntentService` and its `onHandleIntent()` method. Then, change your `BroadcastReceiver` to a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` and [follow the instructions for using it](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second Argument of `openOrCreateDatabase()` must be `SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory` which is optional and it is required in order to instantiate any Cursor by default. Use the value `null` as second argument, if you don't want to instantiate.

```
db=SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME,myContext.MODE_PRIVATE,  null);
```

If you want to instantiate, then try the below code:-

```
db=SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME,new SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory() {
                     @Override
                   public Cursor newCursor(SQLiteDatabase db, SQLiteCursorDriver masterQuery, String editTable, SQLiteQuery query) {
                                //Assign the values of masterQuery,query,editTable as per your requirements
                                return new SQLiteCursor(masterQuery,editTable,query);
                            }
                            },  null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer is in your question - [second argument should be SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler))

Try to put null as second argument.